# Indicating Key Signature Change

Tags: notation, key, key-signatures

Key of C Key Signature has no symbol, so say I was notating music in G Major then wanted to change to the Key of C, how would I show this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing accidentals in the key signature is done with the natural symbol. Put a natural symbol on the position of each accidental you want to cancel, *and reiterate the ones that are left*.

[image]

In the above:

- Cmaj cancels all 3 sharps of Amaj.
- Gmaj cancels 2 sharps of Amaj and reiterates the one left.
- Fmaj cancels the sharp of Gmaj and notes the new flat.

As Tim notes in his answer,

1. adding double bar line before the key change is correct notation;
2. with many accidentals, the change can get pretty long:
   [image]

Comment: I can't imagine any composer wanting to modulate from seven sharps to seven flats (or vice versa), but my classical favorite Gustav Mahler did [6♯ → 6♭](http://archives.nyphil.org/index.php/artifact/287f046b-e1e5-4f88-bf96-b9c52316a5db/fullview#page/38/mode/2up) in his unfinished 10th Symphony.

Comment: @pr1268 7 flats is C♭ major, which is the enharmonic equivalent of B major, which is 5 sharps. So from 7 sharps you can modulate to 5, and then modulate enharmonically. It's not far fetched. Ditto for the opposite direction.

Answer (score 8):

You create a new signature containing just of one [natural sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_(music)) on the same line, where the sharp was before, so nothing remains in effect.

See als my [answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/53671/2600) to closely related question for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to cancel the previous key signature, so a natural sign (♮) on the F line(s) will be sufficient.

Going the other way (i.e. from C to G) will require merely a ♯ sign on the 'F' line. With more ♯s or ♭s, the new key signature will have naturals cancelling the previous unwanted ♯ or ♭ — a weird key signature with more info than usual!

I tend to put a double barline (both thin) at that point, as it's often the start of a new part anyway, but also to point out the key change clearly … especially in C to something else, or something else to C. Obviously going from lots of ♯s/♭s to C will show up as lots of naturals, though.

Comment: Not really "weird" with "more info that usual". Historically, naturals were always written to cancel existing sharps or flats in a new key signature (even when going from say 4 sharps to 2 sharps). However the modern convention is that this is only done when the new signature has no sharps or flats - i.e. C major or A minor.

Comment: @alephzero - by weird I meant we're used to seeing only #s *or* bs in any given key sig. Not a mixture (except for a key change...).

Answer (score 0):

Current practice is to insert enough naturals to cancel the previous key signature when moving into the open key.  Otherwise just put the new key signature.